# Payment confirmation using Authorize.net in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, authorize.net

I have a single authorize.net account, and I have 5 different e-commerce applications tied to that account. Some are posting from a public site and some are posting from managed access sites. I am using SIM and I have read about the Relay Response, but as far as I can tell I can only have one URL listed. That will not work for me as I need a different URL for each different point of entry into the e-commerce system.

My problem at the moment is that I need to update a datafield via a guid upon successful payment completion to confirm purchase of a digital item, but if I put in a relay response page it is getting sent to all my access points and throwing errors. Other parts of the e-commerce system need to send different emails upon completion etc, plus all the urls are different at the top level.

Is there some other way of accomplishing this task that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/)*. It's Authorize.Net's equivalent of Paypal's IPN. It will only post to one URL per account but it happens behind the scenes. This means you can send a custom flag along with each transaction identifying which site the purchase is for and then have it respond accordingly (e.g. send emails, update database, etc).

*I am the author of this content